# C++ accessing a variable in a union struct

Tags: c++, struct, member, unions

I am working with a library who has a struct defined as such:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    union {
        struct {
            y;
            union {
                int z;
            } innerStruct;
            char *a;
        } middleStruct;
    int q;
    } u;
} mainStruct;
```

How do I access char* a?

I have tried multiple methods. This works:

```
mainStruct *myStruct;
int d = myStruct->x;
```

But this does not work:

```
char *d = myStruct->a;
```

I can get x fine using the above method but not a. why?

I have never worked with unions before and I am forced to use this struct as part of the library I need. Thanks for the help in advance and sorry if I am butchering this question.

Comment: `myStruct->u.middlestruct.a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can get x fine using the above method but not a. why?

Because `x` is a member of `mainStruct`, but `a` isn't.

`a` is a member of `middleStruct` which is a member of `u` which is a member of `mainStruct`. You can access members of union instances using the same syntax as you access members of non-union class instances. So, you can write `myStruct->u.middleStruct.a`

P.S. The behaviour of `mainStruct->u` is undefined unless you first initialize `mainStruct`.

Answer (score 1):

The field `x` is a direct member of `mainStruct`, so it's natural that this works:

```
int d = myStruct->x;
```

The field `a` is a member of `middleStruct`, which is a variant of `u`, which is member of `mainStruct`. It's more deeply nested than `x`, so you need to navigate the data structure like this:

```
char *d = myStruct->u.middleStruct.a;
```